# How to search in Word for spaces that are on the beginning of a new line

Tags: microsoft-word, search, wildcards

I have the following issue. I recently wrote a macro that allows me to replace all TAB insertions in a text with a space. This is a must as in the frame I am working in, as it happens a lot (context: document clean-ups after conversions).

Now the one frame where this is bad (thus that a TAB is converted to a space) is when the TAB is on the beginning of a new line. In that specific case it would be better if the TAB was converted to nothing, so the first thing on the beginning of the line would be the a symbol (e.g. the paragraph begins with " xxx", while it should begin with "xxx").

I tried to fix this with the word search function by using wildcards, but to no avail. I thought that I could search for something like "[!?] ?" (thus this would imply, by my reasoning, that Word should search for all instances where there is no symbol at first then there is a space and then there is any symbol). Searching for "^p " also doesn't seem to do the trick.

Would you have any suggestions as to how to solve the issue?

Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching with wildcards for `([^l|^13])( )` will find a line break - both manual and paragraph breaks - with a following blank (and put them into separate groups). Use `\1` in the replace field to omit the blank, but retain the line break.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this, works like a charm! Could you perhaps explain how this works `([^l|^13])( )` and also if perhaps there exists a wild card library (the windows one is quite limited)? This is the first time I saw the expression `^13` for example.

Comment: Okay, let's start with `()`. Those are used to create searching groups. Those groups can be later referenced in the replacement field. `([0-9])([a-z])` will find a number followed by a letter, puts the number in group 1 and the letter in group 2. If you now use the replacement `\2 \1` you insert the found letter (group 2) followed by the found number (group 1). `^l` finds manual line breaks, `^13` those before a paragraph. Unfortunately I don't know if there is some kind of library, I just found them on a [German wiki site](http://www.augenbit.de/wiki/index.php?title=Erweiterte_Suche_in_Word)

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. I will take a look at the wiki (I speak German so it is not a problem). Thanks once again!